# how to create a dynamic datagrid in flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic, datagrid

I am trying to create a datagrid in FLEX. The trouble is that I want it to be 100% dynamic - i.e. columns & data.

Basically I need to populate the datagrid via a result set from a database query, this data will be gathered via a standard java spring jdbc dao layer. The query is as generic as 'select * from tablename', so the result set can change from query to query.

My plan is to convert this result set into some form of java object, my initial thought is a Map of some kind that will contain the column name and values for a row.

The bit Im struggling with is that I need to convert this result set into a ActionScript object (via graniteds) that I can then use to populate a datatable.

I have seen lots of examples on how to dynamically add columns to the datagrid, and tie in the data via the datafield object - but Im stuck as to how I do this if I dont know how many columns I will have or what the column names will be.

hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know, how to create columns dynamically, then what causes you to be stuck?
Extract values from database. Convert result to `ArrayList<Map>`. Then in actionscript it will be mapped to ArrayCollection (of `Object`). Since each object in collection will have the same structure (properties), you can easily create datagrid:

```
public function resultEventHandler(event:ResultEvent) {
    var res:ArrayCollection=event.result;
    if (!res || res.length == 0)
        return;
    var dg:DataGrid=new DataGrid();
    var typicalObj:Object=res.getItemAt(0);
    var columns:Array=[];
    //iterate through object properties
    for (var prop:String in typicalObj) {
        //set header text and dataField for new column
        var c:DataGridColumn=new DataGridColumn(prop);
        columns.push(c);
    }
    dg.columns=columns;
    dg.dataProvider=res;
    //add your datagrid on stage, do it as you need
    view.addElement(dg);
}
```

Comment: Note, that this example is for `mx datagrid`, if you want to use spark, columns should be `ArrayCollection`, just an observation.